# Setting title of UINavigationbar not working

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I've looked through a few online tutorials, but nothing is working.

That's the code of my viewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UINavigationController {

    let textView = UITextView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // tried this
        self.navigationItem.title = "AAA"

        // and this
        self.title = "AAA"

        // and finally this
        self.parent?.title = "AAA"
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this isn't working (I haven't used a navigation bar before)

I didn't change anything in the main.storyboard.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Are you sure that your ViewController Embed with NavigationController? and your View controller class will be class ViewController: UIViewController { }

Comment: How do I add a navigationbar then. If I use "class ViewController: UIViewController {
} " I cant use "self.navigationBar...."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all in your storyboard select your view controller and then

Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller

then in your `ViewController` class add

```
self.title = "AAA"
```

in your `viewDidLoad` method and your code will look like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "AAA"
    }
}
```

You need to replace `UINavigationController` with `UIViewController`

Answer (score 2):

Select **ViewController** from the storyboard.

Go to the Editor and Embed with Navigation Controller

[image]

**1) Select Navigation Item and set title from the storyboard.**

[image]

**2) By Programmatically**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Your Title"
    }
}
```