# How do I add top navigation to a form in Eureka programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm fairly new to using Swift and this is my first time using Eureka to create forms. I'm having trouble figuring out how to add a "Done" button on the top of the screen to return the user back to the main view from the form view.

I've tried using

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Done"
```

and a couple of other solutions I've found on the internet with no luck.

```
class EntryFormViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title = "New Entry"
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = false
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Done"
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .red

        // Form

    }
}
```

There is no navigation bar at all with this code, no back button, no title.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:

Here's some code of where I'm using the Form.

```
@objc func insert() {
        items.append("Item \(items.count + 1)")
        let insertionIndexPath = NSIndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [insertionIndexPath as IndexPath], with: .automatic)
        let nextViewController = EntryFormViewController()
        self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: show more code where you use `EntryFormViewController`

Comment: Make sure that your `EntryFormViewController` Embed with `NavigationController`. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55631352/10150796

Comment: added some more code

Comment: and I'm not using storyboards so I'm not sure that I can embed in ````NavigationController````

Comment: Your view controller must be attached with any navigation controller so that you can add Navigation items on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}
```

add this code your navigationbar might be hidden and I hope your problem will be solved

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately this didn't change anything.